# ¿Como es que las funciones reciben argumentos bajo el capó sin ser explícitamente escritos? JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Buenas tardes a todos/as. Tengo una consulta que tiene que ver más con términos teóricos ya que es tan confusa la pregunta que se me dificulta formularla.

Supongamos que tenemos el siguiente código (Utilizando la librería de ReactJS):

```
const BudgetFilterGUI = () => {
  const [budgetValue, setBudgetValue] = useState(0);

  const handleSearchClick = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const result = searchBudget(Number(budgetValue));
    console.log(result);
  }
  return(
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={() => handleSearchClick()}>
            <input
              type="number"
              name="budgetFilterInputField"
              placeholder="Search products according to your budget."
              style={{width: "360px"}}
              onChange={(event) => setBudgetValue(event.target.value)}
            />
          <button
            onClick={() => handleSearchClick()}
            >
            Search
          </button>
   </div>
);
```

¿Como es posible que se envíen argumentos (como el objeto `event`) sin ser explícitamente escrito como argumento al momento de llamar a la función `handleSearchClick()`?

¿Como es posible que pueda acceder a él directamente como `event.preventDefault()` sin siquiera iterar sobre el objeto `arguments` (el cuál es parte del prototipo de la función desde su definición)?

**Juro que esto no es ninguna tarea, solo me estoy comiendo el cerebro hace días.**

Comment: Checa esto: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event

Comment: react compila a js... por lo tanto, lo que ves es como se escribe algo en react... si vamos a ver a js, seguro recibe los parametros que corresponde...

Comment: Resumen del enlace proporcionado por @BetaM: Si el evento no se proporcionó por parámetro, Javascript "entenderá" que se trata del que está disponible en contexto global `window.event` y será el que use para aplicar `.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es parte de Javascript y ReactJS, en el onClick bien le puedes pasar una funcion o una referencia a una funcion, ahora en este caso le pasas una funcion por defecto al ser un evento internamente tiene argumentos ocultos los cuales javascript los utiliza por decirlo de forma implicita como ser el 'event':

**Forma explicita:**

```
onClick={(e)=> handleSearchClick()}
```

**Forma implicita:**

```
onClick={() => handleSearchClick()}
```

Ahora como tienes una funcion declarado afuera puedes **llamarlo por referencia**:

```
onClick={handleSearchClick}
```